# How to prevent jquery ajax call firing twice, I am using jquery 2.1.4

Tags: jquery

I have a table with repeated check boxes, when I check the check box, it calls java web service and updates the status for that record; since the AJAX call is made twice, its going to the error section;
 How to avoid making call twice; I tried async: false, did not work; After looking at some sites, tried using e.preventDefault(), adding this makes call once but, the check boxes wouldn't get uncheck and do not disappear; 
The expected behavior is when check box is checked, make service call and change the status to pending and disappear the checkbox;

Comment: Mind...showing your code..?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: show your code snippet

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rummy/ukk1nskj/ ; On click on check box, should get status from java service and replace the check box with status

Comment: Don't do the thing that causes the request twice.

Comment: use this $(".error-status .ready-for input").click(function(){}); instead of $(".error-status .ready-for input").on(function(){});

Comment: @NegiRox what difference does it make? `click()` uses `on()` internally anyway

Comment: yes, i changed to .click(), i still see in my debug, before the first request completes, the second request comes in while i am debugging; FYI- im not clicking twice; Here is the fiddle code  
jsfiddle.net/rummy/ukk1nskj

Comment: where is the HTML in this fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the click event handler for each checkbox like this:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var clickedBox = $(this);
    functionToDisplayCheckboxAsPending(clickedBox);
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success : function(response) {
            functionToHandleCheckboxSinceItSucceded(clickedBox);
        },
        error : function(errorThrown) {
            doSomethingAfterError(clickedBox);
        }
    });
};
```

You should then define something that you want to do after the first click on the checkbox through `functionToDisplayCheckboxAsPending(box)`, including the disabling of it so you cannot click it twice (you can remove the click action too).

The after the ajax call succeeds, you can define what to do with that checkbox under functionToHandleCheckboxSinceItSucceded.

The key here is that you have the object with the clicked checkbox to handle within each function and you can play around with the events for it depending on the Ajax call status.

Comment: I click check box only once, but ajax call made twice; how to prevent firing it twice;

Comment: What's your actual code? Because that is not supposed to happen if clicked once.

Comment: Here is the code snippet in fiddle; 
jsfiddle.net/rummy/ukk1nskj

Comment: @user3072213 you are not passing any event to the on() function but only the handler. Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for it. Can you try my suggestion to adapt your code? By the way, you don't need to set async to false, you can just implement `functionToDisplayCheckboxAsPending()` to hide it or whatever while the ajax call is still working.